# Empty uri and localName in DefaultHandler

Tags: java, rss, rss-reader

I am developing an RSS reader. When running this code, localName and uri empty. I am parsing a RSS feed.
I am running the following code. The same code is working fine in another android project.

```
@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {

    String name;
    if (localName == "" ){
        name = qName;
    }
    else{
        name = localName;
    }

    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
        currentPost.setTitle(chars.toString());
    }
    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
        currentPost.setLink(chars.toString());
    }
    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("content")
            && currentPost.getContent() == null) {
        currentPost.setContent(chars.toString());
    }
    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
        currentPost.setFeed(feed);
        Posts.Instance().add(currentPost);
        currentPost = new Post();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the API

> Parameters:
>
> uri - The Namespace URI, *or the empty string if the
> element has no Namespace URI or if Namespace processing is not being performed.*
>
> localName - The local name (without prefix), *or the empty
> string if Namespace processing is not being performed.*
>
> ...

and

> The characters method can get called multiple times while inside a
> tag, especially if the element value contains whitespace.

In characters() docs

> The Parser will call this method to report each chunk of character
> data. SAX parsers may return all contiguous character data in a single
> chunk, or they may split it into several chunks; however, all of the
> characters in any single event must come from the same external entity
> so that the Locator provides useful information.

therefore,

> When I write SAX parsers, I use a StringBuilder to append everything
> passed to characters():

```
public void characters (char ch[], int start, int length) {
    if (buf!=null) {
        for (int i=start; i<start+length; i++) {
            buf.append(ch[i]);
        }
    }
}

Then in endElement(), I take the contents of the StringBuilder and do something with it. That way, if the parser calls characters() several times, I don't miss anything.
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7182648/643500 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/2838338/643500

**Edit::**

Read http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2008/07/rss-feed-client-in-java.html

Comment: Thanks for these information. The same feed works fine in an android project but not in a classical java project.