# SAX parsing problem with white space in Android

Tags: android, whitespace, saxparser

I m doing with SAX parsing for all my projects and it works nicely. But today I faced a problem while accessing the same SAX. Following is the part of the xml where am getting problem.

```
<customCssStyle label="css1" order="1" text=".test { background-color: yellow; } .link { background-color: red; }"/>
```

While parsing with SAX I can get the values of "label" and "order". but in case of "text" I am facing problem. This value comes in 2 strings. I think it's due to white space.

Am i right? Can SAX not recognize the white space? Should I use Pull parsing?

Answer (score 0):

The `characters()` method may be called several times for each element. It's up to you to maintain all the characters read so far, in a `StringBuilder` for example, and append the new characters each time until `endElement()` is reached.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838099/android-sax-parser-not-getting-full-text-from-between-tags) and its accepted answer for full details.

Comment: I think you cant get my question. Sorry for bad english. Actualy I can do the parssing and got the values also but in case of "text" i got 2 strings like .test { background-color: yellow; }  and  .link { background-color: red; } . But It should be one string